# How to traverse and build a multidimensional dictionary without using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion

I have a json message where at the highest level, I have a dictionary with unknown depth and structures, and am looking to traverse it to format it, ending up with a new, formatted dictionary.  After using timeit, I found it to be very slow and discovered that recursion in python is not very quick at all.  All that being understood, I don't know how to actually transform my recursive function "Foo.format_it" into a loop based one, if possible.

```
import time
import json
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_out = {}
        self.msg_in  = None
        self.sample_data = """
        {
            "data": {
                        "a": "",
                        "b": "",
                        "c": "127.0.0.1",
                        "d": 80,
                        "e": {"f": false,"g": false,"h": false,"i": false,"j": false,"k": false},
                        "l": [ {"ii": 2, "hh": 10, "gg": 200, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": 3, "ee": 0},
                               {"ii": 5, "hh": 20, "gg": 300, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": -1, "ee": -1},
                               {"ii": 5, "hh": 30, "gg": -400, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": -1, "ee": -1}],
                        "m": true,
                        "n": true,
                        "o": 1000,
                        "p": 2000,
                        "q": "",
                        "r": 5,
                        "s": 0,
                        "t": true,
                        "u": true,
                        "v": {"jj": 5, "kk": 0, "ll": 10, "mm": 9, "nn":  [ { "aa": 20, "bb": 30 }, { "aa": 20, "bb": 30 } ] }
                    }
        }
        """
    def format(self, msg_in):
        print msg_in
        self.msg_in = json.loads( msg_in )
        self.msg_out = {}
        self.format_it(self.msg_in, self.msg_out)
        import pprint
        print pprint.pformat(self.msg_out)
        return json.dumps( self.msg_out )

    def ff(self, val, out_struct):
        if int(val) < 0:
            out_struct[u'ff'] = ""
        else:
            out_struct[u'ff'] = str(val)

    def format_it(self, item, out_struct):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for dict_key, dict_val in item.iteritems():
                if dict_key in dir(self):
                    dict_key = getattr(self, dict_key)(dict_val, out_struct)
                if dict_key:
                    if isinstance(dict_val, dict):
                        out_struct[dict_key] = {}
                        self.format_it(dict_val, out_struct[dict_key])
                    elif isinstance(dict_val, list):
                        out_struct[dict_key] = []
                        self.format_it(dict_val, out_struct[dict_key])
                    else:
                        out_struct[dict_key] = dict_val
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            for list_val in item:
                if isinstance(list_val, dict):
                    out_struct.append({})
                    self.format_it(list_val, out_struct[-1])
                elif isinstance(list_val, list):
                    out_struct.append([])
                    self.format_it(list_val, out_struct[-1])
                else:
                    out_struct.append(list_val)
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tic = time.clock()
    f = Foo()
    f.format(f.sample_data)
    print (time.clock()-tic)
```

Here is the in data and out data per request, in the simplest case, only the key 'ff' needed to be formatted and so -1 became an empty string:

```
[IN]
        {
            "data": {
                        "a": "",
                        "b": "",
                        "c": "127.0.0.1",
                        "d": 80,
                        "e": {"f": false,"g": false,"h": false,"i": false,"j": false,"k": false},
                        "l": [ {"ii": 2, "hh": 10, "gg": 200, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": 3, "ee": 0},
                               {"ii": 5, "hh": 20, "gg": 300, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": -1, "ee": -1},
                               {"ii": 5, "hh": 30, "gg": -400, "aa": -1, "bb": -1, "ff":-1, "cc": -1, "dd": -1, "ee": -1}],
                        "m": true,
                        "n": true,
                        "o": 1000,
                        "p": 2000,
                        "q": "",
                        "r": 5,
                        "s": 0,
                        "t": true,
                        "u": true,
                        "v": {"jj": 5, "kk": 0, "ll": 10, "mm": 9, "nn":  [ { "aa": 20, "bb": 30 }, { "aa": 20, "bb": 30 } ] }
                    }
        }
[OUT]
{u'data': {u'a': u'',
           u'b': u'',
           u'c': u'127.0.0.1',
           u'd': 80,
           u'e': {u'f': False,
                  u'g': False,
                  u'h': False,
                  u'i': False,
                  u'j': False,
                  u'k': False},
           u'l': [{u'aa': -1,
                   u'bb': -1,
                   u'cc': -1,
                   u'dd': 3,
                   u'ee': 0,
                   u'ff': '',
                   u'gg': 200,
                   u'hh': 10,
                   u'ii': 2},
                  {u'aa': -1,
                   u'bb': -1,
                   u'cc': -1,
                   u'dd': -1,
                   u'ee': -1,
                   u'ff': '',
                   u'gg': 300,
                   u'hh': 20,
                   u'ii': 5},
                  {u'aa': -1,
                   u'bb': -1,
                   u'cc': -1,
                   u'dd': -1,
                   u'ee': -1,
                   u'ff': '',
                   u'gg': -400,
                   u'hh': 30,
                   u'ii': 5}],
           u'm': True,
           u'n': True,
           u'o': 1000,
           u'p': 2000,
           u'q': u'',
           u'r': 5,
           u's': 0,
           u't': True,
           u'u': True,
           u'v': {u'jj': 5,
                  u'kk': 0,
                  u'll': 10,
                  u'mm': 9,
                  u'nn': [{u'aa': 20, u'bb': 30}, {u'aa': 20, u'bb': 30}]}}}
```

The code is a bit pared down and uses tic/toc vs timeit.  In using both, the execution of just the recursion seems to be around .0012s (where I even remove the object creation and json load from the time calculation).

Comment: Please post a sample input and expected output for `format_it`. I could read your code and understand what it does, but I doubt my accuracy is going to be super high, given how sleepy I am right now

Comment: Sure thing, the post has been updated.

Comment: Do you know that it is the recursion being slow, or is it the step by step, element by element construction of your new nested dictionary. An alternative might be to simply do a deepcopy of your in dictionary, and the recursively traverse it looking for keys of interest. It might be just as slow, but it might rule out(or in) recursion being the actual problem.

Comment: In general, if you can't figure out how to make a recursive function iterative, do it in the generic mechanical way—add a `while True` with a `break` in the base case, and an explicit stack of arguments to the recursive calls in the recursive case, and then a `for` loop over `reversed(stack)` after the `while` loop. Then loop for ways to refactor and simplify. You should end up in roughly the same place you would have by converting at a higher level.

Comment: @tonysuffolk66 your comment motivated me, and I got a 6x increase by not doing the dir(self), and swtiching over to fn = lambda x,y: dict_key, and just doing the singular if getattr(self, dict_key, fn)(dict_val, out_struct).  So perhaps that was the only problem?